# Calculate the duration from start date and end date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.

```
select DISTINCT caseNumber, dateStarted,dateStopped from patientView where dateStarted !='' and dateStopped != '';
```

We get the following output,

| CaseNumber | dateStarted | dateStopped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-04 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-19 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-10 |
| 4 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-11 |
| 4 | 2022-01-13 | 2022-01-14 |
| 4 | 2022-01-21 | 2022-01-23 |
| 5 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-16 |
| 5 | 2022-01-17 | 2022-01-24 |
| 5 | 2022-01-24 | 2022-01-26 |
| 8 | 2022-01-17 | 2022-01-20 |
| 8 | 2022-01-21 | 2022-01-28 |
| 11 | 2022-01-18 | 2022-01-25 |
| 11 | 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-27 |

I want to calculate the duration for each caseNumber. For eg. caseNumber 1 has 2 rows and hence total duration would be 18days.

Comment: If you have stored your dates correctly as date or datetime datatypes you won't veantbto compare then to an empty string.

Comment: I suspect you want `sum` and `group by`.

Comment: @DaleK just used formatted text.

Comment: Please reformat your query, which I had already done for you, but you overwrote with your changes.

Comment: Please add your desired results.

Comment: Generally speaking, use of DISTINCT is rarely needed. It is often a sign of developer desperation when trying to fix a logic fault.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `group by` keyword to group redundant case numbers and take the min for the startdates and max for stopdates. You can do something like:

```
SELECT caseNumber, max(dateStopped)-min(dateStarted)
from patientView
where dateStarted != '' and dateStopped != ''
GROUP BY caseNumber;
```

Comment: How does that give days?

Comment: Thank you  @Siesmic_ . I modified the code to get the days.
'
SELECT caseNumber,min(dateStarted) as dateStarted,  max(dateStopped) as enddate , DATEDIFF(day, min(dateStarted), max(dateStopped) ) AS DateDiff
from patientView
where dateStarted != '' and dateStopped != ''
GROUP BY caseNumber;
'

Comment: But what about case 4? There are gaps so I don’t think min/max will produce the correct results, I’d think you’d want ```SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,DateStarted,DateStopped))``` instead

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you want the sum of the durations for individual patientView records or the duration from the earliest start to the latest end. It is also not clear whether the stop date is inclusive or exclusive. Is 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-04 considered 3 days or 4 days?

Here is code that shows 4 different calculations:

```
DECLARE @patientView  TABLE (CaseNumber INT, dateStarted DATETIME, dateStopped DATETIME)
INSERT @patientView
VALUES
    (1,  '2022-01-01 ', '2022-01-04'),
    (1,  '2022-01-05 ', '2022-01-19'),
    (2,  '2022-01-03 ', '2022-01-10'),
    (4,  '2022-01-05 ', '2022-01-11'),
    (4,  '2022-01-13 ', '2022-01-14'),
    (4,  '2022-01-21 ', '2022-01-23'),
    (5,  '2022-01-15 ', '2022-01-16'),
    (5,  '2022-01-17 ', '2022-01-24'),
    (5,  '2022-01-24 ', '2022-01-26'),
    (8,  '2022-01-17 ', '2022-01-20'),
    (8,  '2022-01-21 ', '2022-01-28'),
    (11, '2022-01-18 ', '2022-01-25'),
    (11, '2022-01-26 ', '2022-01-27')
    
SELECT
    CaseNumber,
    SumDaysExclusive = SUM(DATEDIFF(day, dateStarted, dateStopped)),
    SumDaysInclusive = SUM(DATEDIFF(day, dateStarted, dateStopped) + 1),
    RangeDaysExclusive = DATEDIFF(day, MIN(dateStarted), MAX(dateStopped)),
    RangeDaysInclusive = DATEDIFF(day, MIN(dateStarted), MAX(dateStopped)) + 1  
FROM @patientView
GROUP BY CaseNumber
ORDER BY CaseNumber
```

Results:

| CaseNumber | SumDaysExclusive | SumDaysInclusive | RangeDaysExclusive | RangeDaysInclusive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 19 | 18 | 19 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 | 12 | 18 | 19 |
| 5 | 10 | 13 | 11 | 12 |
| 8 | 10 | 12 | 11 | 12 |
| 11 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 10 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3bdb3f4f49d0ae594a4665cf7f75c50e)

The test data above uses DATETIME types. (DATE would also work.) If you have dates stored as character data (not a good practice), you may need to add CAST or CONVERT statements.

Comment: your answer is correct. The exact information required is SumDaysExclusive. 

One more challenge which I am facing are patients who have left treatment halfway need to be excluded. This means for eg. lets say patient 8 didn't take the treatment 2, when a patient is noted 2 times it means he is treated by another dose. Sometimes they leave halfway and I need to exclude them from the calculation. 

Any ideas about it.

Comment: After the `GROUP BY`  you could add `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` or `HAVING SUM(DATEDIFF(day, dateStarted, dateStopped) + 1) >= 2`, depending on whether or not you wish to include patients with a single multi-day visit.